# Glassfish to Jboss 6 eap migration

Tags: glassfish, jboss-eap-6

is there any migration guide available for application Server Glassfish to JBoss 6 EAP. I am particularly intrested in server side configuration(Installing, configuration etc) and the important points taken into account if any while migration (Except the code changes)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something is being worked on, but it says it's [coming soon](http://www.jboss.org/migration/). Your best bet for now would probably be to ask in the [forums](https://community.jboss.org/en/jbosseap) or if you have a support contract for EAP 6 there might be some other types of help available.